# cannot properly mock Notification API

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have the following in my setupTests.ts:

```
globalThis.Notification =  ({
    requestPermission: jest.fn(),
    permission: "granted",
} as unknown) as jest.Mocked<typeof Notification>
```

However, I keep getting this error in my jest test in a react project:

```
TypeError: Notification is not a constructor

  21 | export function showNotification(title: string, notificationText: string) {
  22 |     if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
> 23 |         const notification = new Notification(title, {  // params});
```

How to fix it to mock Notification API properly?

Comment: Is that surprising? Your test double of Notification is an object with one method and a string property, which _isn't_ a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar problem. I used the following method to mock the Notification. Visual studio code kept complaining about the way I was mocking the object, but the test still ran perfectly.

I was able to add a mock function for close, which I could test later using expect.

```
    const mockClose = jest.fn();

    global.Notification = jest.fn().mockImplementation(
      () =>
        (({
          close: mockClose,
        } as unknown) as Notification)
    );

    functionInCode(data); <--- Calls new Notification

    expect(global.Notification).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mockClose).toBeCalledTimes(1);
```